# Can't find my Nexus 6 under devices in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Installed Android Studio and tried to launch an app. I can choose from different emulator, but I can't find my phone. I have connected it to my computer, enabled debugging in Developer Options, and I have tried to update the drivers from device manager in Windows, but Windows keep saying the best drivers are already installed. Anyone else had this problem? Really appreciate a solution.

Comment: Do you want to run app directly on your phone or on emulator equivalent to your phone?

Comment: Directly on my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Install the phone ADB to your pc from the internet, then from the device manager update the driver using the files you downloaded from the previous step, enjoy!
You can read more from this link [USB Drivers](https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html)

Comment: Would that be the same as the USB Driver from Google?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/
You have to update "android device"-driver manually in the windows device manager.

Comment: I always choose Android Composite ADB Device and never had a problem.